# How to use @Autowire when using @ParameterizedTest in Junit5

Tags: junit5

I currently use SpringBoot1.5 and Junit5.
How do I use @autowire to dependency injection when I use the annotation @ParameterizedTest for parametric testing because I need to interact with the database.

I try to use

```java
TestContextManager testContextManager = new TestContextManager(getClass());
testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);
```

but it will cause the @transaction to be unavailable.

this my code

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public abstract class AbstractUnitTest {
}

public class PatientFacadeTestParameterized extends AbstractUnitTest {
...
    @Autowired
    PatientFacade patientFacade;(is null)
...

    @Transactional
    @ParameterizedTest(name = "{index}: {0}")
    @YamlFileSource(resources = {"logistics/patient_facade.yaml"})
    public void testCreateAccountPhonePatienta(PatientFacadeData patientFacadeData) {
      ...
    patientFacade.createAccountPhonePatient(patientForm1);
      ...
    }
...
```

I just want to use @ParameterizedTest to manage my input.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 1.5.x depends on Spring Framework 4.3.x, but the latter does not provide built in support for JUnit Jupiter (a.k.a., JUnit 5).

So, if you want to use Spring Framework 4.3.x with JUnit Jupiter, the only option is to use my [spring-test-junit5](https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5) project.

Once you have configured the dependency on `spring-test-junit5`, you will have access to the `SpringExtension` for JUnit Jupiter. This replaces the `SpringRunner` for JUnit 4.

You should then be able to rewrite your test class in a manner similar to the following. I cannot provide you an exact working example, since I do not have access to the types in your project.

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class PatientFacadeTestParameterized {

    @Autowired
    PatientFacade patientFacade;

    @Transactional
    @ParameterizedTest(name = "{index}: {0}")
    @YamlFileSource(resources = {"logistics/patient_facade.yaml"})
    public void testCreateAccountPhonePatienta(PatientFacadeData patientFacadeData) {
        // ...
        patientFacade.createAccountPhonePatient(patientForm1);
        // ...
    }
```

What is responsible for injecting the `PatientFacadeData` into your test method? Does `@YamlFileSource` take care of that?

By the way, you should practically never need to use the `TestContextManager` directly in your tests. The `SpringRunner` and `SpringExtension` handle that for you.